# Iterating through an Array for .Text values

Tags: c#, arrays, iteration, tic-tac-toe

I am making a Windows Forms Tic-Tac-Toe program that has a grid size set by a value in the App.config file. So if the value is 9, the grid is the regular 3 x 3, if its 25, its a 5 x 5 etc.

I have a Gameboard class that makes the actual buttons for the array:

```
public Gameboard(int numberofButtons) //Constructor method that is referencing the App.config for the dimensions value to make the board
{
    buttonArray = new Button[numberofButtons]; //creating an array the size of numberofButtons which is the dimensions value from App.config
    Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 36.0f); //creates an instance of the Font class
    int sqrtY = (int) Math.Sqrt(numberofButtons);
    int z = 0; //Counter for array

    //Create the buttons for the form
    for (int x = 0; x < sqrtY; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < sqrtY; y++)
        {
            buttonArray[z] = new Button();
            buttonArray[z].Font = font;
            buttonArray[z].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
            buttonArray[z].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100*y, 100*x);
            buttonArray[z].Click += new EventHandler(button_click);
            z++; 
        }
    }
}
```

If i want to check for win patters in the array by simply checking the value of buttonArray.Text for positions in the buttonArray, how can I iterate through that?

for example in a 4x4 grid, the winlines for horizontal wins would be

```
0,1,2,3
4,5,6,7
8,9,10,11
12,13,14,15
```

so

```
x=0, x<sqrt(dimension), x++
buttonArray[x].Text == "X" <-- to test
```

I realize this is really poorly coded and confusing but I am trying to do this with a single dimension array because that is what the teacher asked for. I want to check the values of `buttonArray[]` for a value, first checking the rows, then the columns, then the diagonals.

The Form has no buttons so when the Form loads it populates it with the buttons used for the grid. It is meant to play against the computer so when you click a button, the .Text becomes "X" and then the computer is supposed to put down an "O" and so on.

Comment: So, important question I probably should of asked first. Do you need to know how the X/O won or just that X or O won or all the cells are filed/draw. For example, "X Won (Row 1)" or just "X Won". If the first example, what about if the last cell to win made a full row and column, do have you show any/all ways that they won?

Comment: Well, I would ideally like to know WHO won and then change the background color of the winning pattern or make a WinLine appear from the coordinates of the endpoints of the winning line. At least change the .BackColor to something like IndiaRed to highlight the winning buttons that combined to make the winline.

Comment: That should be the easy part, you have to check if someone won (the more difficult part) after each turn, so whoever's turn it was just won (if the game is a win). You can't play a turn and lose!

Answer (score 2):

I'm providing examples of how to separate out the criteria you specified. I'm more than willing to answer specific questions, but as this is a homework question I don't want to provide everything. Hopefully this helps.

```
string[] values = buttonArray.Select(b => b.Text).ToArray();


//uses integer divison to separate out rows
string[][] rows = values
    .Select((v, i) => new {index = i, value = v})
    .GroupBy(anon => anon.index/size)
    .Select(grp => grp.Select(anon => anon.value).ToArray())
    .ToArray();

foreach(string[] row in rows)
{
    //Pseudocode
    var winner = CheckAllValuesArePopulatedAndTheSameAKAWinner(row);
    if (winner exists)
        return winner;
}

//uses modulus to separate out columns, basically a transpose
string[][] columns = values
    .Select((v, i) => new { index = i, value = v })
    .GroupBy(anon => anon.index % size)
    .Select(grp => grp.Select(anon => anon.value).ToArray())
    .ToArray();

string[] diagonal1 = values
    .Select((v, i) => new {index = i, value = v})
    .Where(anon => anon.index%(size + 1) == 0)
    .Select(anon => anon.value) //take just the string value, drop the index
    .ToArray();

string[] diagonal2 = values
    .Select((v, i) => new { index = i, value = v })
    .Where(anon => anon.index % (size - 1) == 0)
    .Skip(1) //skip 0 index
    .Take(size) //skip last index
    .Select(anon => anon.value) //take just the string value, drop the index
    .ToArray();
```

Indices Example:

```
//given size and dimension

//run this code once per different size, not on each check (probably move variable to some outer scope)
Dictionary<string, int[]> winningSets = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
int[] indices = Enumerable.Range(0, dimension).ToArray(); //make array of 0 to (dimension - 1)


for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < size; ++rowNum) //0 based row index/num
{
    int[] rowIndices = indices
        .Where(i => i / size == rowNum)
        .ToArray();
    winningSets.Add(String.Format("Row Number {0}", rowNum + 1), rowIndices); //use 1 based row index/num for display
}

for (int colNum = 0; colNum < size; ++colNum) //0 based row index/num
{
    int[] colIndices = indices
        .Where(i => i % size == colNum)
        .ToArray();
    winningSets.Add(String.Format("Column Number {0}", colNum + 1), colIndices); //use 1 based column index/num for display
}

int[] diag1 = indices
    .Where(i => i % (size + 1) == 0)
    .ToArray();
winningSets.Add("Diag TR to BL", diag1);

int[] diag2 = indices
    .Where(i => i % (size - 1) == 0)
    .Skip(1) //skip 0 index
    .Take(size) //skip last index
    .ToArray(); 
winningSets.Add("Diag TL to Br", diag2);

//run this for each check
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int[]> winningSet in winningSets)
{
    //Pseudo
    if (all of winningSet.Value indices are populated and same)
        return winningSet.Name; //Name of winning set, ex will not return multiple winning set which is possible in this game
    //this example does not show who won, but whoever had the last turn is the winner if one is found.
}
```

Adding a example of how to check an array of values (representing a row/column/diagonal)

```
    string CheckWinner(string[] setOfValues)
    {
        if (setOfValues.Any(individualValueFromSetOfValues => String.IsNullOrEmpty(individualValueFromSetOfValues))) // some values/cells are not filled in so no winner here
            return null; 
        if (setOfValues.Distinct().Count() == 1) //all data is the same
            return setOfValues.First(); //any value would work, we just checked that they're all the same
        return null; // all values/cells are full but they are not all the same
    }
```

Comment: Does the array have columns and rows if its just a one dimensional array? I was looking at it more of a formula-based search through an array of numbers, and then trying to test the .Text property of the buttonArray associated with the various winning number positions.

Comment: The code is based on a one dimensional array. The top two will return a grouping, the bottom two will return an IEnumerable of I,anon. I'll adjust it a bit to return IEnumerable of the value's type

Comment: Ok, I changed the code. A one-dimension array has an index, it doesn't have columns or rows; it could be perceived as a single row with columns. If you explain the "formula-based" idea more I might be able to expand on that.

Comment: so for example if "dimensions" is equal to 25, meaning a 5x5 grid, each "side" is equal to 5. So if a variable x=0 i can say that the first vertical win line would be [x, x+side, x+2*side, x+3*side, x+4*side] and the second vertical win line, with x = x+1 would be the same formula. And there has to be "side" number of like values in a row to be a win for any grid.

Comment: I think I'm really dumbing down the problem, but in essence, if I have a grid of area "dimensions" and "side" is the sqrt(dimensions), meaning the grid is side x side. I want to test the .Text properties of "side" amount of buttons in buttonArray for equality based on formulas for win lines. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's what I did in the example but for x = 0 to (side - 1). A flattened example of the 5x5 for the columns would be x = 0 and i were i is the index of a 1D array would be the results i % side = x, so you'll have index of 0, 5, 10, 15, 20 returned. By using this manner, your formula/result array can have "side" number of elements.

Comment: I responded while you were typing the last comment, so you want to return all possible combination of indices that meet a full row, column, or diagonal. Then you can pass the set of indices to some method to test all of them?

Comment: Is there any chance that you can add as many comments as possible to your coding examples so I can follow along with it? Pretty much everything there is unfamiliar to me so I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what the process is and thank you for all your help already.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that last comment, I think yes that sounds like what I am trying to do. When I started I first wrote out a few grids of different sizes (3x3, 4x4, 5x5) and figured out how a vertical winline is calculated, same with diagonal and horizontal, and now I want to use those formulas to test the .Text properties of the Buttons in those spots of the buttonArray either for a value or for equality and then a value

Comment: I tried to add as much as possible, couple reminders. Don't just check for equality among values because you can also have equality of empty strings (start scenario). Use.Equals instead of == for string comparisons.

Comment: I think I get more of whats happening in the second example but its still over my head. Let me ask you this way: Lets say i have an array of Buttons called buttonArray. Lets say I have a variable named "side" that is equal to the height/width of the grid the buttons make up (ex: buttonArray  has 49 buttons, side = 7). How can i test "sign" amount of buttons for equality in the Text they have displayed. And I would be choosing each button via a formula, so something like buttonArray[x].Text == buttonArray[x+variable].Text etc

Comment: Sorry didn't see the previous comment again before posting

Comment: Quick comment, then long explanation; a 2D array/matrix is an array of arrays all with the same length in programming. So explanation, all the code I used is using LINQ, the expression can be applied to any 1D collection(* 2D noted more below). Anyways, LINQ allows you apply a multitude of operations to a collection. Instead of getting into small details, you should probably Google "C# LINQ" and look for "Lamba Expression" examples. Back to 2D a lil, lets say you have int[x][y]. A LINQ expression will be on the int[x] collection, a collection of int[y]'s.(MIND OVERLOAD) I know, just Google :-D

Comment: What about using something like regular expression to test the Text of the Buttons in the grid for "side" amount in a row?

Comment: Oh man this is quite literally blowing my mind. Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Added another piece, if you want to go with LINQ - which if you have the time I suggest - to help you along, I tried to spell out a little more how the .Any works (and most Lamba Expression works). Also included a few more LINQ methods in it that you may be able to read and get the general idea. I think this will help show you my first approach.